# Visual Studio 2010 Fonts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, command-prompt

Hey is it possible to use the font used as the default font in the CMD as a font in visual studio 2010?

Thanks,

Comment: Courier New? Yes you can use any installed font in almost any area. Ensure its a fixed width font or your code will look horrible.

Answer (score 2):

here is the link if you want to change fonts in command prompt

Link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/22/customize-the-command-prompt-vstiptool0058.aspx

and if you want to change font in visual studio 2010 the go to

TOOLS->Options->Environment-> Fonts and Colors and set it to you desired settings

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `Consolas` font both for cmd.exe and for programming. I think it is much prettier than Courier new (but, obviously, that's a matter of preference)